# CORS anywhere reads old file

Tags: javascript

I am using cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com in a javascript file in website A to read a text file from website B and it is working correctly .
The problem is , when I change the text file in website B still the CORS anywhere reads the old file .
Suppose that the text file name is file1.txt if I change the content of this file and use CORS anywhere
it reads the old content but if I rename the file1.txt to file2.txt and using CORS anywhere it reads the new content .
Any body knows what is the reason for this problem ?

Comment: Add a cache parameter to your link. Something like `"file1.txt?Cache=" + +new Date`.

Comment: I used  'file1.txt?Cache='+(new Date()).getTime()   and  problem  is solved and CORS any where reads the new content  ,  Thank you